# Change prices according to supply and demand

Tags: java, minecraft

Currently, I am working on a project shop (minecraft) which consists of varying the prices of the store according to demand.

For the purchase, if a lot of people buy, the price goes up and vice versa
  For sale, the more sales there are, the lower the selling price, and vice versa

I have a list storing all available shop like this

```
public class Shop {

    private ItemStack itemStack;
    private Location location;
    private double prix;
    private int vente;
    private ShopType shopType;
    private ShopCategorie shopCategorie;
    private ShopItemMenu shopItemMenu;
    private String name;

    public Shop(ItemStack itemStack, Location location, double prix, int vente, ShopType shopType, ShopCategorie shopCategorie, String name){
        this.itemStack = itemStack;
        this.location = location;
        this.prix = prix;
        this.vente = vente;
        this.shopType = shopType;
        this.shopCategorie = shopCategorie;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ShopCategorie getShopCategorie() {
        return shopCategorie;
    }

    public void setShopCategorie(ShopCategorie shopCategorie) {
        this.shopCategorie = shopCategorie;
    }

    public ItemStack getItemStack() {
        return itemStack;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public double getPrix() {
        return prix;
    }

    public ShopType getShopType() {
        return shopType;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getVente() {
        return vente;
    }

    public ShopItemMenu getShopItemMenu() {
        return shopItemMenu;
    }
}
```

the sales variable allows to increment the number of sales on this panel shop, which will allow us to vary its price. I would like to make a system that recalculates prices every 3 hours via a task.

My only question is: What do you advise I do to calculate the price change depending on demand.